# What exactly happens in memory when we allocate an array using an empty curly braces?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, heap-memory

Both of the following examples return 0, if we call `length`:

```
int[][] b = {};
```

or

```
int[] a = {};
```

I think two objects are allocated on the heap as usual: I suppose that in the second case, an object (empty array) of type `int[]` is allocated, but in the first case?

What exactly is going on under the hood in these situations?

Answer (score 2):

A 2 dimensional array is an *array of arrays* and all *arrays are objects* themselves. So *under the hood* compiler will make the same `newarray` call with a slight difference.

Java code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] b = {};
    int[] a = {};
}
```

Byte code :

```
stack=1, locals=3, args_size=1
   0: iconst_0
   1: anewarray     #19    // [][] . array of arrays --[I
   4: astore_1
   5: iconst_0
   6: newarray       int   //[] array of int
   8: astore_2
   9: return
```

Answer (score 1):

`int[] a = {};` is equivalent to `int[] a = new int[0];`

`int[][] b = {};` is equivalent to `int[][] b = new int[0][];`